# Is there a way to know if 3 circles intersect in a point : Java - Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geometry, android-drawable

For start I have **3 points** : **A,B,C** 
The points are placed in a **grid**. The grid is actually an **ImageView** in a **FrameLayout** and both of them are inside a **RelativeLayout** 
 
The **3 points** are places on **RelativeLayout**, **on top of** the **grid**.
 
Now the 3 points represent the **center** of a **circle** with different radius each time(doesn't matter), so when I place the 3 points I draw a circle around each of them.
 
The circles are drawn like this :

```
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.circle);
            GradientDrawable gradientDrawable = (GradientDrawable) drawable;
            gradientDrawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.transparent));
            gradientDrawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.OVAL);
            //Then scale it 
            gradientDrawable.setStroke(stroke,color);
            circles[i].setImageDrawable(gradientDrawable);
```

Now I now both **the (x,y)** of the **3 points** as well as **their radius** 
Is there a way to find if **the 3 cirlces intersect in one or more pixels?**

**EDIT**: 
[Example of 3 circles that intersect in a point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CW9G.jpg)

Comment: adding some figure helps your explanation. I can't understand your problem

Comment: You can use answers at [circle-circle intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349125/circle-circle-intersection-points). You can solve by pairs (circles A & B, circles A & C, circles B & C) and compare the intersections found.

Answer (score 0):

You have the following data, representing your 3 circles:

```
For each circle i=1,2,3:
Center: Ci = (ai, bi)
Radius: ri > 0
```

For three circles to have a common intersection point `(x, y)` that point has to be a solution to the system of quadratic equations:

```
(x - a1)^2 + (y - b1)^2 = r1^2
(x - a2)^2 + (y - b2)^2 = r2^2
(x - a3)^2 + (y - b3)^2 = r3^2
```

Expand each equation and rearrange the terms:

```
x^2 + y^2 - 2*a1*x - 2*b1*y = r1^2 - a1^2 - b1^2
x^2 + y^2 - 2*a2*x - 2*b2*y = r2^2 - a2^2 - b2^2
x^2 + y^2 - 2*a3*x - 2*b3*y = r1^2 - a3^2 - b3^2
```

One trick is to rewrite the system as follows:

```
z - 2*a1*x - 2*b1*y = r1^2 - a1^2 - b1^2
z - 2*a2*x - 2*b2*y = r2^2 - a2^2 - b2^2
z - 2*a3*x - 2*b3*y = r1^2 - a3^2 - b3^2
x^2 + y^2 = z
```

It is an over-determined system of three linear equations and three unknown variables `(x, y, z)`, plus one extra quadratic equation between these three variables `x^2 + y^2 = z`.

So, solving linear systems is easy, therefore run the following algorithm:

**Step 1:**
Reduce the linear system

```
z - 2*a1*x - 2*b1*y = r1^2 - a1^2 - b1^2
z - 2*a2*x - 2*b2*y = r2^2 - a2^2 - b2^2
z - 2*a3*x - 2*b3*y = r1^2 - a3^2 - b3^2
```

by subtracting the first equation from the second and the third:

```
z = 2*a1*x + 2*b1*y + r1^2 - a1^2 - b1^2
2*(a1-a2)*x + 2*(b1-b2)*y = r2^2 - a2^2 - b2^2 - r1^2 + a1^2 + b1^2
2*(a1-a3)*x + 2*(b1-b3)*y = r1^2 - a3^2 - b3^2 - r1^2 + a1^2 + b1^2
```

**Step 2:** Solve the two by two linear system for (x, y):

```
2*(a1-a2)*x + 2*(b1-b2)*y = r2^2 - a2^2 - b2^2 - r1^2 + a1^2 + b1^2
2*(a1-a3)*x + 2*(b1-b3)*y = r1^2 - a3^2 - b3^2 - r1^2 + a1^2 + b1^2
```

and find the solution (or solutions, in some degenerate cases, but generally there should be exactly one solution) `(x, y)`.

**Step 3:**
Calculate `z` by substituting every solution `(x, y)` from Step 2 in the formula:

```
z = 2*a1*x + 2*b1*y + r1^2 - a1^2 - b1^2
```

**Step 4:**
Check if

```
x^2 + y^2 = z
```

If it is, then the three circles intersect at the point `(x, y)`. If none of the solutions `(x, y, z)` from Step 3 satisfy the quadratic equation, then the three circles do not intersect.