# Creating an elbow joint between shoulder and hand

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5, khan-academy

I've been trying to make a function that returns the position of an elbow joint based on arm segment length and the shoulder and hand's position. However, my method isn't working, despite my best efforts!

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;

var r = 0;
while(dist(x, y, p1x, p1y) > segLength-1 && dist(x, y, p1x, p1y) < segLength+1 && dist(x, y, p2x, p2y) > segLength-1 && dist(x, y, p2x, p2y) < segLength + 1){
    r ++;
    
    x = 200 + (cos(r) * segLength);
    y = 200 + (sin(r) * segLength);
}
```

I know there are two different points at this distance, and I'd like to pick the one that makes the most sense as an elbow joint (usually the lower one)

I am using Khan Academy's Processing environment, so I cannot use ES6 syntax (sadly).

Comment: I think the point lies on the intersection of 2 circles one centered on each point x & y with radius segLength.

Comment: Yes, but how do I find the intersection point?

Comment: This might help: https://www.analyzemath.com/CircleEq/circle_intersection.html

Comment: @exside, I couldn't understand what that was saying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Circle-circle intersection points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3349125/circle-circle-intersection-points)
helped me with this.

here is the working code below, doing what I originally wanted it to do (draw an arm)

```
// from stack overflow
//{
// Let EPS (epsilon) be a small value
var EPS = 0.0000001;

// Let a point be a pair: (x, y)
function Point(x, y) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
}

// Define a circle centered at (x,y) with radius r
function Circle(x,y,r) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.r = r;
}

// Due to double rounding precision the value passed into the Math.acos
// function may be outside its domain of [-1, +1] which would return
// the value NaN which we do not want.
function acossafe(x) {
  if (x >= +1.0){return 0;}
  if (x <= -1.0){return 360;}
  return Math.acos(x);
}

// Rotates a point about a fixed point at some angle 'a'
function rotatePoint(fp, pt, a) {
  var x = pt.x - fp.x;
  var y = pt.y - fp.y;
  var xRot = x * Math.cos(a) + y * Math.sin(a);
  var yRot = y * Math.cos(a) - x * Math.sin(a);
  return new Point(fp.x+xRot,fp.y+yRot);
}

// Given two circles this method finds the intersection
// point(s) of the two circles (if any exists)
function circleCircleIntersectionPoints(c1, c2) {

    var r, R, d, dx, dy, cx, cy, Cx, Cy;
    
    if (c1.r < c2.r) {
        r  = c1.r;  R = c2.r;
        cx = c1.x; cy = c1.y;
        Cx = c2.x; Cy = c2.y;
    } else {
        r  = c2.r; R  = c1.r;
        Cx = c1.x; Cy = c1.y;
        cx = c2.x; cy = c2.y;
    }
    
    // Compute the vector <dx, dy>
    dx = cx - Cx;
    dy = cy - Cy;
    
    // Find the distance between two points.
    d = Math.sqrt( dx*dx + dy*dy );
    
    // There are an infinite number of solutions
    // Seems appropriate to also return null
    if (d < EPS && abs(R-r) < EPS){return [];}
    
    // No intersection (circles centered at the 
    // same place with different size)
    else if (d < EPS){
        return [];
    }
    
    var x = (dx / d) * R + Cx;
    var y = (dy / d) * R + Cy;
    var P = new Point(x, y);
    
    // Single intersection (kissing circles)
    if (abs((R+r)-d) < EPS || abs(R-(r+d)) < EPS){return [P];}
    
    // No intersection. Either the small circle contained within 
    // big circle or circles are simply disjoint.
    if ( (d+r) < R || (R+r < d) ){return [];}
    
    var C = new Point(Cx, Cy);
    var angle = acossafe((r*r-d*d-R*R)/(-2.0*d*R));
    var pt1 = rotatePoint(C, P, +angle);
    var pt2 = rotatePoint(C, P, -angle);
    return [pt1, pt2];

}
//}\\

function drawArm(startX, startY, endX, endY, segLength){
    var Circle_1 = new Circle(startX, startY, segLength);
    var Circle_2 = new Circle(endX, endY, segLength);
    
    noFill();
    
    /*
    strokeWeight(2);
    ellipse(Circle_1.x, Circle_1.y, Circle_1.r*2, Circle_1.r*2);
    ellipse(Circle_2.x, Circle_2.y, Circle_2.r*2, Circle_2.r*2);
    */
    
    var points = circleCircleIntersectionPoints(Circle_1, Circle_2);
    
    /*
    for(var i = 0; i<points.length; i++){
        strokeWeight(8);
        point(points[i].x, points[i].y);
    }
    */
    
    points.sort(function(a, b){
        return b.y - a.y;
    });
    
    line(startX, startY, points[0].x, points[0].y);
    line(endX, endY, points[0].x, points[0].y);
}

draw = function() {
    background(255, 255, 255);
    
    drawArm(50, 200, 200, 200, 100);
};
```

- some minor modification could be done to prevent errors